# Different reference headings using chapterbib

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm writing my thesis, in which I have a few chapters.
Each chapter is included as a separate file.
I use `chapterbib` to generate a separate reference list at the end of each chapter by the following command:

```
\bibliographystyle{apsrev} \bibliography{ref},
```

the references are listed in the `ref.bib` file.

Everything works like a charm until I tried to make the last chapter a list of my publications. The publication list has a heading "Bibliography", which is the same as that in previous chapters.
My question is, is it possible to get rid of this heading only in the last chapter while keeping "Bibliography" for the other chapters?
I know there is a command `\renewcommand{\refname}{The-name-I-want}`, but it works equally for all chapter-bibliographies.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your document contains chapters, probably the command to redefine is `\bibname` and not `\refname`.

So, to achieve what you want, you can write, for the last bibliography:

```
{\renewcommand{\bibname}{The-name-I-want}\bibliography{ref}}
```

instead of simply

```
\bibliography{ref}
```

In this way the change is kept local to that bibliography.

P.S.: if `\bibname` is undefined, try with `\refname`.

Comment: it works as desired. That's just fantastic! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @D-K You're welcome. Happy it helped.